# How to locate bug only by a memory address?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I got a segment error in a object like this:

```
http_client_reset(struct http_client *client) {
    if (client->last_req) {
         /* @client should never be NULL, but weather
            a valid object, I don't know */
        ...
    }
}
```

by debugging the core dump file in GDB, the memory address of `client` is **`0x40a651c0`**. I have tried several times, and the address is the same.

Then I tried the `bt` command in GDB:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0804c80e in http_client_reset (
    c=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x40a651c0>, 
    c@entry=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x40a651bc>)
    at http/client.c:170
Cannot access memory at address 0x40a651bc
```

there is no back trace message, I have `grep`ed my source code, and there is only one call on `http_client_reset`.

- How to debug such a bug via **only a memory address**?
- Is there a way to judge a object is valid before access its field(except `obj == NULL`)?

Comment: Try using `disass` in gdb to disassemble the current function. And no, there is no way to determine if an object is valid when it's a "bad" value.

Comment: Well, you really have only one anchor there: `at http/client.c:170` put in extra debugging information at that point.

Comment: Valgrind is your friend: http://valgrind.org

Answer (score -1):

Never a coredump crash debugging is a 'Black and White' matter.So you would not be able to get an exact answer for the questions pertaining to debugging coredump. However, most coredump will be due to programming errors which can be classified into broad areas. I will provide some of these broad areas and some debugging mechanism - which might help you.

---

**Class of programming error leading to crash**

1. *multi-threaded code* - check for missing critical section while accessing common data. This can corrupt the data leading to such crash. In your case you can check for http_client pointer, access of this and `CRUD` - Create/Read/Update and Delete.
2. *Heap Corruption* - In most of the cases, this would be a valid pointer and due incorrect handling of heap in another section of code, this may cause the valid pointer to be overwritten. Think of an array in and around the pointer location - ABW etc kind of issues would easily cause this problem.
3. *Stack Corruption* - This is very unlikely, but hard to find them. In case you overwrite stack data - similar to array in the above example - but on stack, then the same issue will occur.

---

**Ways to un-earth the coredump root cause**

You need understand that - technically coredump is an illegal operation causing un-handled exception leading to crash. Since most of it are related to memory handling, a static-analysis tool - such as `kloc/PCLint` would capture almost 80% of the issues. Then I would next run on `valgrind/purify` and would most probably uncover the rest of the issue. Very few issues miss both of them - which would be some sequencing/timing related code - which can be found out with `code review`.

HTH!